# In the Python interactive interpreter, is there any way to refer to the results of the last command?

Tags: python, python-interactive

When I'm using the Python interactive interpreter, I frequently find myself doing this:

```
>>> a = "starting value"
>>> foo(a)
"something I don't want"
>>> bar(a)
"what I wanted"
>>> a = bar(a)
```

Is there any way to just do:

```
>>> bar(a)
"what I wanted"
>>> a = thing_from_before
```

That is, is there any way to refer to the variable that was printed out by the last command that I ran?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is in the variable `_`:

```
>>> 2+2
4
>>> _
4
```

Note that this is not "what was *printed*", it is the value of the previous expression.  So if `bar(a)` just prints something and doesn't return the value, `_` won't help you.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, I was unable to find this in all of my internet searches.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IPython instead of the vanilla interpreter, you can use the `In` and `Out` dictionaries to refer to arbitrary results from the past:

```
In [1]: 2 + 2
Out[1]: 4

In [2]: Out[1] + 2
Out[2]: 6

In [2]: Out[1] + 4
Out[2]: 8
```